# How to force CORE opengl profile on GTK3? (#version 330)

Tags: c++, opengl, gtk

Here's how I'm creating my GTK OpenGL context

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glx.h>
#...

void OpenGLArea::on_realize()
{
    Gtk::DrawingArea::on_realize();

    on_glx_init();

    // Initialize GLEW
    glewExperimental = true; // Needed for core profile
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to initialize GLEW");
    }

    std::cout << "Vendor: ........... " << glGetString(GL_VENDOR) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Renderer: ......... " << glGetString(GL_RENDERER) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Version: .......... " << glGetString(GL_VERSION) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "GLSL version: ..... " << glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION) << std::endl;

    glInit();
}

void OpenGLArea::on_glx_init()
{
    GLint glx_attrs[] = {
        GLX_RGBA,
        GLX_RED_SIZE,
        8,
        GLX_GREEN_SIZE,
        8,
        GLX_BLUE_SIZE,
        8,
        GLX_ALPHA_SIZE,
        8,
        GLX_DEPTH_SIZE,
        24,
        GLX_STENCIL_SIZE,
        8,
        GLX_DOUBLEBUFFER,
        False,
        None,
    };

    xdisplay = GDK_WINDOW_XDISPLAY(Glib::unwrap(get_window()));
    drawable = GDK_WINDOW_XID(Glib::unwrap(get_window()));
    const std::unique_ptr<XVisualInfo, XVisualInfoDeleter> visual_info(glXChooseVisual(xdisplay, DefaultScreen(xdisplay), glx_attrs));

    if (!visual_info)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("failed glXChooseVisual.");
    }

    context = glXCreateContext(xdisplay, visual_info.get(), nullptr, True);
    if (!context)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("failed glXCreateContext.");
    }

    if (!glXMakeCurrent(xdisplay, drawable, context))
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("failed glXMakeCurrent.");
    }
}
```

However, I'm unable to use `#version 330` in my shaders. I've searched lots of places but I can only find how to do it in GLEW. I want to do in the GTK/GL libraries (I don't know how to distinguish what is from Open GL and what is from GTK)

Comment: An example [here](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Tutorial:_OpenGL_3.0_Context_Creation_(GLX)) Pay attention to `context_attribs[]`, Set *major/minor* to 3/3 and add `GLX_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK_ARB, GLX_CONTEXT_CORE_PROFILE_BIT_ARB`

Comment: @Ripi2 I'm unable to find similar functions for GTK3. In this example it uses X11 directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave up trying to tweak configuration options and simply modified this example: https://github.com/agrechnev/gtkmm-fun/tree/master/glarea0 which simply works